# Woodpecker method on chess sites

Tags: tactics

Is there any chess site that allows you to train tactics by repeating some number of problems over and over again?

Comment: Chessables has that functionality in addition to that it offers the book on the woodpecker method https://www.chessable.com/the-woodpecker-method/course/10582/

Answer (score 3):

I think [Chessable](https://www.chessable.com) is pretty close to what you want. There are courses made usually by masters, some are free, some with a price. But you can create your own course and study it too. After you study something, you need to repeat the same problem after some time.

The repetition type has 3 choices:

- **Chessable Spaced Repetition:** It is a special repetition type where the time between repeats are getting longer and longer (like 1 day - 3 days - 1 week ...).
- **Cyclical:** Repeat times are constant (like 1 day - 1 day - 1 day ...).
- **Custom:** This needs Pro Chessable account, you can set the times whichever you like.

For cyclical, there is a note like this from Chessable:

> If you are following the Woodpecker cycle, after you complete the first cycle and the exercises start popping up for review, you can now go and set a shorter cycle, which you can do, by changing the cycle end date again, to say, two weeks from the date at the end of your first cycle.